# How to add breeze.bridge.angular to my build process with wiredep

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, breeze, wiredep

I'm trying to use Breeze with my AngularJs application.

I added breeze to my bower dependencies using:

```
bower install --save-dev breeze-client
```

This command added the dependency to my bower.json file as follows:

```
"dependencies": {
   //Other dependencies here
   "breeze-client": "~1.5.4"
}
```

The thing is that I'm using wiredep with gulp to automate my build process, but when wiredep adds my dependencies it only injects the breeze.debug.js file as follows:

```
<script src="/bower_components/breeze-client/breeze.debug.js"></script>
```

Therefore, when I add this dependency to my core module in Angular it doesn't find the 'breeze.angular' module dependency

```
(function () {
'use strict';

    angular
         .module('app.core', ['breeze.angular']);
})();

// This is the thrown error
// Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module breeze.angular due to:
// Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'breeze.angular' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I know this is the error because when I add this reference manually, it works perfectly.

So my final question is: how can I add (after the breeze.debug.js dependency) the breeze.bridge.angular.js dependency located in the build/adapters folder using wiredep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by editing my bower.json file. Overriding my breeze angular main dependency as follows:

**bower.json file**

```
"overrides": {
    "breeze-client": {
        "main": ["breeze.debug.js", "build/adapters/breeze.bridge.angular.js"],
    }
}
```

This way I am referencing the main file and then the breeze.bridge.angular.js file. Now my bower dependencies are added as I need:

```
<!-- bower:js -->
// Previous dependencies
<script src="/bower_components/breeze-client/breeze.debug.js"></script>
<script src="/bower_components/breeze-client/build/adapters/breeze.bridge.angular.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
```

Now everything is working perfectly

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. That fixed my issue as well.